# Why does focusing a textarea not work without a setTimeout of 0?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a button to edit a div which turns it into a textarea. I use this code because I want the cursor to appear at the end of the textarea after I begin editing:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

   this.state = { body: "asdf" };

  this.messageItemRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
  let length = this.state.body.length;

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.messageItemRef.current.focus();
    this.messageItemRef.current.setSelectionRange(length, length);
  }, 0);
}


render() {
  return ( 
    <textarea ref={this.messageItemRef} value={this.state.body} />
  );
}
```

I randomly decided to try the `setTimeout` of 0 after it was only working when I clicked the edit button and not when I used a hotkey to edit it.

I'm wondering, why is the setTimeout of 0 needed? If I get rid of it, it only focuses the end of the textarea when I click the button, and not when I use the keyboard hotkey.

Why is this?

Comment: Show more code, fella.